Method `new_page` of `BrowserContext` doesn`t work as expected in `Playwright`
I use playwright with pytest. Here are content of my coftest.py file and file with tests test_keplr.py. For some reason, method new_page works as expected in fixture context_use_args_async, but fails everywhere else, except this fixture.
When the program evaluates a line with context.new_page, it opens new page, but endlessly  await this coroutine(method).
conftest.py
import pytest
import os
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pytest_asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser, Playwright, BrowserContext

load_dotenv()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def extension_dirs(tmp_path_factory) -> list[str]:
    extensions_path = Path(os.getenv('TEST_EXTENSION_PATH'))

    temp_dir = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('extensions')

    extension_zips = [
        path for path in extensions_path.iterdir() if str(path).endswith('.zip')
    ]

    extension_dirs = []

    for path in extension_zips:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            extension_dir = temp_dir / path.name.replace('.zip', '')
            zip_ref.extractall(extension_dir)
            extension_dirs.append(str(extension_dir))

    return extension_dirs


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session')
async def playwright_async() -> Playwright:
    playwright = await async_playwright().start()
    yield playwright
    await playwright.stop()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session')
async def browser_async(playwright_async) -> Browser:
    chromium = playwright_async.chromium
    browser = await chromium.launch(headless=False, channel='chrome')
    yield browser
    await browser.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session')
async def context_async(browser_async) -> BrowserContext:
    context = await browser_async.new_context()
    await context.new_page()
    yield context
    await context.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session')
async def browser_use_args_async(playwright_async, extension_dirs) -> Browser:
    extensions_str = ','.join(extension_dirs)

    browser = await playwright_async.chromium.launch(
        headless=False,
        args=[
            f'--disable-extensions-except={extensions_str}',
            f'--load-extension={extensions_str}'
        ]
    )
    yield browser
    await browser.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session')
async def context_use_args_async(browser_use_args_async):
    context = await browser_use_args_async.new_context()
    yield context
    await context.close()


test_keplr.py
import pytest
from playwright.async_api import BrowserContext
from playdegen.async_api.abc import BrowserExtension
from playdegen.async_api.wallets.keplr import Keplr


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_sign_up(context_use_args_async: BrowserContext) -> None:
    page = await context_use_args_async.new_page()
    ...

I tried to use different browsers (chrome and chromium) but it didn`t help.
